# K-Medoids Cluster Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, analysis

What are some analysis functions which can be used on the K-Medoids algorithms?

My main aim is to compare results of 2 different clustering results in order to see which is better.

Can SSE (sum of squared errors) be applied to K-Medoids algorithm?

Comment: have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_%28clustering%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original k-medoid publication discusses the measures ESS, along with several other measures such as average dissimilarity, maximum dissimilarity, diameter that may be more appropriate to use.

SSE is closely related to Euclidean distance, so it usually is not appropriate (unless, of course, you use Euclidean; but why would you use k-medoids then instead of k-means?)

Comment: I am going to use k-medoids instead of k-means as I am going to use custom distance measures rather than Euclidean. So the best approach that I found was to use k-medoids and input a distance matrix.

Comment: Consider hierarchical clustering, too. But either way, read the original paper, to understand the motivations and evaluation measures they used. They may - or may not - be appropriate for your problem. **Don't use SSE unless using Euclidean distance!**

Comment: Why would you use k-medoids instead of k-means in case of Euclidean distance? Probably in case of smaller data sets (as k-medoids complexity is greater) - to ensure that the center of each cluster will be one of the members of the original dataset and so to obtain a clustering more robust to noise and outliers.

Answer (score 0):

ARI, NMI, and Silhouette Coefficient can be used to compare the results